# GeoServer stops responding

Tags: geoserver

I am running on the following setup:

Hardware:

- SuperMirco Server
- 2x Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GH
- 64GB RAM
- RAID 5 SATA array with OS, programs and cached tiles
- RAID 5 SAS array with Postgres data store

Software:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Tomcat 8.5.4
- PostgreSQL 10.2 with PostGIS 2.4.3
- GeoServer 2.9.0 using intergrated GeoWebCache 1.9.0

I have 6 WMS layers which are used by a website (OpenLayers 4.6) and also generate custom images for reports.

For the most part the system is running smoothly but once or twice a week GeoServer stops responding.

- No tiles are served from GeoWebCache and direct requests to GeoServer
  don't generate an image.
- PostgreSQL is still running with no issues.
- I can log into the GeoServer control panel.
- I have tried restarting GeoServer from the Tomcat Web Application Manager and this doesn't solve the issue.
- The only solution I have found is to restart Tomcat.

Any suggestions and/or where to start looking for the problem?